# Proof: Given a non-zero vector $v$ and its coordinate value, prove that it's from exactly one basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space and $v\in V,v\not=0$, and given its coordinate value $(\alpha_i)$ of $v$, how to prove that exists exactly one basis that maps $v$ to $(\alpha_i)$?

$$\begin{array}{}
 &v=\alpha_1v_1+\dots+\alpha_nv_n=\alpha_1w_1+\dots+\alpha_nw_n\\
 \implies &0 = \alpha_1(v_1-w_1)+\dots+\alpha_n(v_n-w_n)
\end{array}$$

then I don't know how to make $v_i=w_i$. Or is that this claim is incorrect? So it's possible that two different bases map some vector $v$ into the same coordinate but not others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check $$(1,3)= 1(1,0) + 3(0,1)$$ and $$ (1,3) = 1(4,3) + 3(-1,0)$$
You have one vector with the same coordinates in two different bases.

Answer (score 1):

Consider bases $\beta_1=\{(1,0),(1,1)\}$ and $\beta_2=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$.  Relative to both bases, we have the same coordinates for $(1,0)$: $(1,0)$.

Comment: Oh well.  You're welcome.